# Need help understanding Java program flow

Tags: java

Code:

```
public static char f( char c ){

 System.out.print( c++ );
       return c--;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       if( f('j') == 'k' || f('f') == 'f'){
          System.out.println( f('d') );
       }
    }
```

Can someone please explain to me why this prints "jde"??
Intuitively, I thought it would print "kged".

Comment: As a learning experience, try changing `f` so that it says `System.out.print(++c);` and then `return --c;` to see what happens!

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of the expression `c++` is the value of `c` BEFORE it gets incremented.  And the value of the expression `c--` is the value BEFORE it gets decremented.

So in the first call to `f` in your example, `c` starts off as `'j'`.  Then the line `System.out.println(c++);` prints `'j'` and increments `c`, so that it's now `k`.  On the next line, it returns the new value of `c`, which is `'k'`.

Since the first half of the `if` condition is true, the second half is not evaluated.  We jump straight into the body of the `if`.  But this works the same way as before - it prints `'d'` and returns `'e'`.  The `'e'` is then printed.

Answer (score 1):

`c++` is incremented after the `System.out.print`, so it prints 'j' first.

The second part of the if statement is not evaluated since `f('j')` returns `'k'` as the decrement is applied after the return.

Then `d` is printed because `f('d')'` is called which first prints 'd' and then the result of the function 'e'.

If you want to understand why a problem is doing something, especially if it is rather unexpected, it is a good idea to get familiar with a debugger. With that you can step through every instruction, and see the state of your program at every execution step.

As an exercise, write a program which is using those functions, but prints `qed` (quod erat demonstrandum).

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition is f('j')=='k' which is true and that is why other condition is not being checked. Here f('j') methods prints j and returns 'k' and after returning c is again 'j'. Now in System.out.println(f('d')); f('d') prints d and returns e which is printing in main method. So the output is jde